# How to dynamically populate AudioSource with multiple audio data from firestore in just_audio?

Tags: just-audio

I have been trying to dynamically populate AudioSource.uri() with data from firestore.

I uploaded some songs into firestore database and I wanted to use the data for a just_audio playlist in my app. I have done everything possible, and I really am not sure why its not working.

I don't want to add the song urls  and other data statically as shown in the plugin example.

Here are my attempts:

First I fetched the song data using a StreamBuilder and passed it as a DocumentSnapshot List to the JustAudioPlaylist() page;

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> _list;
_list = snapshot.data.docs;

Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => JustAudioPlaylist(
                                songs: [_list[index]],
                                
                              ),
                            ));
                      },
                      child:
                          Container(child: Center(child: Text('My Playlists'))),
                    );
                  }),
            )
```

Then, here's the JustAudioPlaylist page where I expected to retrieve and populate the AudioSource.uri().

```
class JustAudioPlaylist extends StatefulWidget {
  final List songs;

  JustAudioPlaylist({this.songs});
  @override
  _JustAudioPlaylistState createState() => _JustAudioPlaylistState();
}

class _JustAudioPlaylistState extends State<JustAudioPlaylist> {
  AudioPlayer _player;
  int _addedCount = 0;
  var _playlist;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _playlist
        .addAll(widget.songs.map((song) => ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
              AudioSource.uri(
                Uri.parse(song['song']),
                tag: AudioMetadata(
                  album: "Science Friday",
                  title: song['songTitle'],
                  artwork: song['songImage'],
                ),
              ),
            ])));
```

I am not sure why its not working, but it produces an error "addAll was called on null". Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relevant code is:

```dart
_playlist.addAll(...);
```

The error means `_playlist` is `null`. That is, `_playlist` is an uninitialised variable and doesn't actually contain any playlist object. I can see you declare the variable so it starts off empty:

```dart
var _playlist;
```

But you never actually store anything into this variable, like `_playlist = ...something...`. So your `_playlist` variable starts off `null` and continues to remain `null`.

You could do this instead:

```dart
_playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);

// and then later...
_playlist.addAll(widget.songs.map(...etc...));
```

Although `addAll` is intended for dynamically modifying the playlist after it's already created. But in your case, you know which songs you want to play at initialisation time, so you may as well just initialise the playlist right at the beginning and you won't have to add to it later:

```dart
_playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
  children: widget.songs.map(...etc...)
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I see what I have been doing wrong. I have followed your instructions carefully, but now I get this error and I have spent the entire day trying everything possible to get around it, but its not working => type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, AudioSource>' is not a subtype of type 'List<AudioSource>'

Comment: Oh.. the error was because I failed to add .toList() after the .map(...etc..). The player now opens and I now see all three songs as expected. But I am faced with these bugs. First bug => The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >(Instance of 'Duration')
StreamBuilder<PositionData> 
Second bug is => The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isEmpty
StreamBuilder<SequenceState>

Comment: If it's about null, you now know what that error means - you forgot to store something into a variable and yet you're trying to use that variable as if it had something stored in it. The error will give you the line number and you can use the debugger to see which variable is null (or just use `print(...)` statements to print out the variables and see which ones are null. Anyway, if you are stuck despite that, you could ask as separate questions.